# Why Angular 5 and NGinx cannot serve javascript and css files?

Tags: nginx, angular5, mime-types, nginx-location

Why Angular 5 and NGinx cannot serve javascript and css files? MIME type is not a valid Javascript . SyntaxError: unexpected token: numeric literal

I am getting the error with Angular 5 - typescript and Nginx server.

error in console

```
The script from “https://my-server.com/organizations/inline.15670a33298d01750cb3.bundle.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type
SyntaxError: unexpected token: numeric literal
```

The Javascript files where also downloaded with the content of the index.html.
Plus, when I was in page "https://my-server.com/organizations" and refreshing the browser, I was sent to the "https://my-server.com/organizations/organizations" url.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was just to change the base href tag in index.html from

```
<base href="">   <-- wrong
```

to

```
<base href="/">   <-- right
```

That was it, no changes in nginx.conf or anything else.